# jQuery - Treat each img element individually without using class or parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

What I'm trying to do is get the image dimensions in src to adjust in accordance to the image's width attribute. (Note the dimension is defined in the url with "s1600" being original size, "s320" being 320px wide etc).

The images in my 450+ articles have no class attribute.

I've managed to get this far with my limited jQuery knowledge but now I'm stuck. As you can see, my code is calculating the first image it finds on the page and is applying those dimensions to every other image thus the bad resolution in other img elements.

```
$('img').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this)
    var imgWidth = $("img").width() + 100
  $this.attr('src',$this.attr('src').replace('s1600','s' + imgWidth))
})
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w576y236/

Comment: How about using $this.width() +100 instead of $("img").width(), http://jsfiddle.net/w576y236/1/ ?

Comment: @LJ_1102 Thank you. That's what I wanted to do!

Answer (score 0):

Here : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w576y236/5/)

**HTML** :

```
<img width="200" src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-NX_ClFb2-Uk/UGJHjrprEAI/AAAAAAAAARk/HD7o4dbV7Wo/s1600/bookshelves-at-the-library_w482_h725.jpg" />
<br/>
<img width="640" src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-NX_ClFb2-Uk/UGJHjrprEAI/AAAAAAAAARk/HD7o4dbV7Wo/s1600/bookshelves-at-the-library_w482_h725.jpg" />
```

**JavaScript** :

```
$('img').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('s1600','s' + parseFloat($(this).css('width'))));
});
```